# An exception whenever a client force closes Aysnc TCP Chat Server

Tags: c#

Whenever a client force closes their connection an exception is thrown stating "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host," and then the Chat Server no longer receives messages from other clients.

How do I handle the fact the client forced closed their connection, remove them, and keep accepting messages from other clients connected?

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket clientSocket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                clientSocket.EndReceive(ar);

                //Transform the array of bytes received from the user into an
                //intelligent form of object Data
                Data msgReceived = new Data(byteData);

                //We will send this object in response the users request
                Data msgToSend = new Data();

                byte[] message;

                //If the message is to login, logout, or simple text message
                //then when send to others the type of the message remains the same
                msgToSend.cmdCommand = msgReceived.cmdCommand;
                msgToSend.strName = msgReceived.strName;

                switch (msgReceived.cmdCommand)
                {
                    case Command.Login:

                        //When a user logs in to the server then we add her to our
                        //list of clients

                        ClientInfo clientInfo = new ClientInfo();
                        clientInfo.socket = clientSocket;
                        clientInfo.strName = msgReceived.strName;

                        clientList.Add(clientInfo);

                        //Set the text of the message that we will broadcast to all users
                        msgToSend.strMessage = "<<<" + msgReceived.strName + " has joined the room>>>";
                        break;

                    case Command.Logout:

                        //When a user wants to log out of the server then we search for her 
                        //in the list of clients and close the corresponding connection

                        int nIndex = 0;
                        foreach (ClientInfo client in clientList)
                        {
                            if (client.socket == clientSocket)
                            {
                                clientList.RemoveAt(nIndex);
                                break;
                            }
                            ++nIndex;
                        }

                        clientSocket.Close();

                        msgToSend.strMessage = "<<<" + msgReceived.strName + " has left the room>>>";
                        break;

                    case Command.Message:

                        //Set the text of the message that we will broadcast to all users
                        msgToSend.strMessage = msgReceived.strMessage;
                        break;

                    case Command.List:

                        //Send the names of all users in the chat room to the new user
                        msgToSend.cmdCommand = Command.List;
                        msgToSend.strName = null;
                        msgToSend.strMessage = null;

                        //Collect the names of the user in the chat room
                        foreach (ClientInfo client in clientList)
                        {
                            //To keep things simple we use asterisk as the marker to separate the user names
                            msgToSend.strMessage += client.strName + "*";
                        }

                        message = msgToSend.ToByte();

                        //Send the name of the users in the chat room
                        clientSocket.BeginSend(message, 0, message.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                                new AsyncCallback(OnSend), clientSocket);
                        break;
                }

                if (msgToSend.cmdCommand != Command.List)   //List messages are not broadcasted
                {
                    message = msgToSend.ToByte();
                    string m = msgToSend.strMessage;
                    string to = pnet_commlib.Main.GetInfo(m, "TO"); // Gets who it's going to from line 1
                    if (to != null)
                    {
                        foreach (ClientInfo clientInfo in clientList)
                        {
                            if (clientInfo.socket != clientSocket ||
                                msgToSend.cmdCommand != Command.Login)
                            {
                                if (clientInfo.strName == to)
                                {
                                    clientInfo.socket.BeginSend(message, 0, message.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                                        new AsyncCallback(OnSend), clientInfo.socket);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (ClientInfo clientInfo in clientList)
                        {
                            if (clientInfo.socket != clientSocket ||
                                msgToSend.cmdCommand != Command.Login)
                            {
                                    clientInfo.socket.BeginSend(message, 0, message.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                                        new AsyncCallback(OnSend), clientInfo.socket);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                //If the user is logging out then we need not listen from her
                if (msgReceived.cmdCommand != Command.Logout)
                {
                    //Start listening to the message send by the user
                    clientSocket.BeginReceive(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), clientSocket);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return;
            }
        }
```